# A Resume Review and Ranking System

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Many employers are looking for a compatible match in their applicants. Some companies (mostly startups), don't have anyone to tell them what criteria to use when looking for hires and ends up making poor decisions. So, I was thinking as **Stack Overflow** is a very reputed service in Software Development circles, it might be a good idea to add a "Resume Review system" as a feature. Of course, it can be a paid service, but it will be really helpful. How it will work is, that it will take the applicants past experiences and accomplishments (only those that can be verified), and then will rank them by their by their countries in accordance with their specific fields.

Of course, there can be more or less to it, this is just a simple proposal. If anybody else have some ideas to it, please share too.

Comment: What you're describing is half the job of a recruiter, and from what I understand one of the points of the entire SO jobs system is to *get rid* of that as much as feasible.

Comment: Plus "x years of experience" is not a valuable piece of information in and of itself. You can be stuck with some technology for ten years, do the same thing every day, and rarely learn anything new.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Some companies (mostly startups), don't have anyone to tell them what criteria to use when looking for hires...

Only people working at a company can know what skills and personal qualities that company needs in a new hire. If they don't know, then nobody can tell them, at least not without some extensive personalized consultation. This is not something that should be crowd-sourced.